The difference between 遠慮 (Enryo) and 配慮 (Hairyo)
Today I had a session with my Japanese language partner. We spoke about the 世代間ギャップ (generation gap).
I asked her what distinguishes her generation from people of older generations and she said, the older people had more 遠慮. The example she gave was "Imagine a box of sweets that are shared among a group. Old people would never eat the last one because they would feel bad about the others not being able to eat it.".
To check my understand I offered this example "Imagine two friends sitting in a bus. They want to chat but know that other people would be annoyed by them because others like a quiet bus. So they don't talk.".
However she said my example is 配慮.
From dictionaries I get that 遠慮 is restraint while 配慮 is consideration. Using the English words they would fit in both examples.
Why does my language partner have such a strong feeling about them being different and what is the nuance making one not suited for either of the example situations?
I can't ask her because neither is her English level high enough nor is my Japanese good enough to do a detailed explanation in either language.

"Restraint" and "consideration" may fit both contexts but they are different things/processes. You worry your action may annoy other people in a public space, namely you are considerate of other people, so you don't do it, which is to exercise restraint. Same with the Japanese words.

@desmo: So, you would answer my question to Enno Shioji with a "Yes"?

What question?  You ask us questions.  What was the question you asked Enno Shioji?

I think restraint vs. consideration describes it well actually. 遠慮 is primarily about not doing something to show respect. The behavior often has the purpose of improving the wellbeing of the other person, but not always - it can just have the purpose to show deference.
配慮 on the other hand can be both about not doing something, but also about doing something. For example, you can say 隣の人に配慮して連絡する but 隣の人に遠慮して連絡する would be wrong. Also, it often does not involve deference (juniors showing respect to seniors). E.g. you can 赤ちゃんに配慮する but not 赤ちゃんに遠慮する. Lastly, 配慮 always has the purpose of improving the wellbeing of the other person. For example, if you say 遠慮して名前を言わない it means you don't say a name to show respect (or to avoid insulting). If you say 配慮して名前を言わない it rather has the nuance you want to protect somebody's privacy, mental health etc.

Thank you for your answer. If restraint and consideration are good there must be a gap between English and Japanese interpretation. If it costs me willpower to not do something I am restraining myself. That works with not talking loud near a baby, not talking at all while there are people near me, or if I really would like to talk about a secret but don't do so. Of course I can do this because I care (consideration) but I can also do it to avoid conflict (restraint). Is it the same in Japanese?

@MerlinNestler The words map quite appropriately whether in English or in Japanese.  Perhaps you restrained yourself on the bus, but the question is why you restrained yourself.  I would ask myself, "why am I not talking?"  Is it out of consideration for others?  Or, is because I don't wish to break a social more?
